# I have an error about smart_text after installing django-admin-charts

Tags: django-admin, python-3.10, django-4.0

I want to have charts in the admin panel,
I installed the **`django-admin-charts`** package,
Which said add these to `settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
         'admin_tools_stats', # this must be BEFORE 'admin_tools' and 'django.contrib.admin'
         'django_nvd3',
)
```

But after adding it, it gives this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'smart_text' from 'django.utils.encoding' (E: \ test1 \ venv1 \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ utils \ encoding.py)
```

I searched but didn't find much about smart_text!
Maybe it has a problem with Django version 4 or Python version 3.10.3?

Comment: i have this problem too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, no one answered.
I had to ignore it with #:
# from django.utils.encoding import smart_text

Answer (score 27):

This is because django-admin-charts needs smart_text and in django 4 smart_text is removed from the utils/encoding so the better way to resolve this issue is to add this code in your settings.py file

```py
import django
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
django.utils.encoding.smart_text = smart_str
```

Answer (score 2):

I digged around a little and the problem seems to be the Django version. `smart_text` function is not present in the `django/utils/encoding.py` file. I downgraded from 4.0.2 to 3.2.13, set PyMemcacheCache as the default cache in settings.py and it works. In my case downgrading is not acceptable as Django.  3.2.13 doesn't support redis cache, but it might help you. Let's hope that django-admin-charts will add suport for Django 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when we switched from Django 2.2 to Django 4 version.
There were a library which was not upgraded. I found this out by searching the usage of "django.utils.encoding import smart_text" statement under the project scope.

The issue resolved once I upgraded the django-wkhtmltopdf library from 3.3.0 to 3.4.0.

Check for any dependent libraries and upgrade as above to fix the issue.