# I'm facing this error "ImportError: cannot import name 'smart_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'"

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm trying to implement Tags on my project using the `django-tagging` package.
Below is the full error.\

> File "C:\Users<user>\Desktop<App>\models.py", line 9, in 
> from tagging.fields import TagField
> File "C:\Users<User>\Desktop<User><App>\env\lib\site-packages\tagging\fields.py", line 9, in 
> from tagging.forms import TagField as TagFormField
> File "C:\Users<User>\Desktop<User><App>\env\lib\site-packages\tagging\forms.py", line 8, in 
> from tagging.models import Tag
> File "C:\Users<User>\Desktop<User><App>\env\lib\site-packages\tagging\models.py", line 8, in 
> from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
> ImportError: cannot import name 'smart_text' from 'django.utils.encoding' ("C:\Users<User>\Desktop<User><App>\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py)

`models.py`\

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
     .....
     tags = TagField()
```

Working with  `django.VERSION (4, 2, 0, 'final', 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have an error about smart\_text after installing django-admin-charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71589827/i-have-an-error-about-smart-text-after-installing-django-admin-charts)

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the removal of `smart_text` from `django.utils.encoding` in `Django 4.0.21`. The error message is raised when a package that depends on `smart_text` is used with `Django 4.0.2 or later1`.

Solution
Add this code in your `settings.py` file1:

```
import django
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
django.utils.encoding.smart_text = smart_str
```